# Recursion to compare two Arrays without using loop [pseudo code]

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion

> Consider the given two arrays A and B without repetitions (that
>   is, no double occurrences of the same element). The task is to check whether
>   each element of B is also an element of A without regard to the order.
>   For instance if A = [1, 2, 3, 4] and B = [2, 3, 1] then the answer is YES. If
>   however B = [1, 2, 5] then the answer is NO because 5 is not in A.
>
> Design a recursive algorithm (no use of loops) for the above problem.

I am trying to solve the above problem, and there is no way I can find to solve it without using the loop. Would anyone know a way to solve this with recursion without using a loop?

I can not use any builtin functions, this is a recursion exercise for algorithms and data structures.

Comment: I have done it using nested loops. That was easy, but I do not know how to do it using recursion WITHOUT using loop...

Comment: You question will be down-voted a lot ... SO is not a `do my problem` type of a site. It is more of `help me figure out what is wrong with my code` type of an idea.

Comment: oh ok, I just joined the site.

Comment: You can recursively iterate and put all elements of A in a map. Now, recursively iterate over B and check if each element exists in map or not. If not, return false, else true.

Comment: How would I write pseudocode for map? I am sorry for asking so basic question.

Comment: What language are you using? Also, what prevents you from simply converting your loops to recursion?

Comment: if the answers here helped you please accept one of them. This has a number of benefits for you, for the answerer and for other users of this site. [stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode for a function that recursively tests whether the array `A` contains a given element, `x` might look something like this:

```
function isMember(x, A):
    if A = [] then return false

    if x = A[0] then return true

    return isMember(x, A[1..-1])
end
```

This function is built on the premise that to test if `x` is a member of `A`, we can test to see if the first element of `A`, denoted `A[0]`, is the same as `x`.  If so, we can terminate the function and return `true`.  If not, then call the function again, passing it all the elements of array `A` **except** the first one that we already tested.  I've denoted the remaining elements of `A` with `A[1..-1]`, i.e. element numbers 1 through to -1, which in some languages is another way to refer to the last element.

Now during the second call to this function, `x` is being compared to the first element of `A[1..-1]`, which is, of course, the second element of `A`.  This recurses over and over, each time shrinking the size of array `A` the element at the top of the list is tested and discarded.

Then we eventually reach the final case, where there are no more elements left in `A` to test, which results in the final recursive call to the function being passed an empty array.  In this situation, we can infer that every element in `A` failed to match with `x`, and so we can safely return `false`, stating the `x` is *not* a member of `A`.

Now, in order to determine whether a given array `B` is contained by array `A`, each element in `B` needs to undergo the test described above.  If `isMember()` returns `true` for every element in `B`, then `B` must be contained by `A`.  If any one element causes `isMember()` to return `false`, then we can stop further testing because `B` contains elements that are not in `A`, so it cannot be a subarray.

Here's some pseudocode that illustrates this recursive process:

```
function containedBy(B, A):
    if B = [] then return true

    let x := B[0]
    if not isMember(x, A) then return false

    return containedBy(B[1..-1], A)
end
```

It's very similar in many ways to the first function, which isn't surprising.  This time, however, array `B` is reduced in size with each recursion, as its lead element is passed through to the `isMember()` function, then discarded upon `isMember()` returning `true`.  As before, the final case after the last recursive call to `containedBy()` passes through an empty list in place of `B`.  This can only mean that every element of `B` successfully passed the membership test with `A`, so we return `true` to confirm that `B` is, indeed, contained by `A`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to turn a simple iterative algorithm -- with a nested loop -- into a recursive one.

An iterative solution, which is not optimised to use a map, but has a *O(n²)* time complexity, would look like this:

```
function includesValue(A, v):
    for i = 0 to length(A) - 1:
        if A[i] == v:
            return true
    return false

function includesArray(A, B):
    for j = 0 to length(B) - 1:
        if not includesValue(A, B[j]):
            return false
    return true
```

If you translate this into a recursive pattern, you could pass the current index as an extra argument:

```
function recIncludesValueAfter(A, v, i):
    if i >= length(A):
        return false
    if A[i] == v:
        return true
    return recIncludesValuesAfter(A, v, i + 1)

function recIncludesSubArray(A, B, j):
    if j >= length(B):
        return true
    if not recIncludesValueAfter(A, B[j], 0):
        return false
    return recIncludesSubArray(A, B, j + 1)
```

You would call it with the third argument as 0:

```
recIncludesSubArray(A, B, 0)
```

Each of the two recursive functions uses this pattern:

- The first `if` block corresponds to the end of the loop in the iterative version
- The second `if` block corresponds to the body of the for loop in the iterative version (including its potential break-out)
- The final recursive call corresponds to the launch of a next iteration in the iterative version.

### Optimised by using a Map/Set

If you would need an optimised version, using a set (a map where only the key is important, not the value associated with it), then the iterative version would look like this:

```
function includesArray(A, B):
    setA = new Set
    for i = 0 to length(A):
        setA.add(A[i])
    for j = 0 to length(B) - 1:
        if setA.has(B[j]):
            return false
    return true
```

Again, we can convert this to a recursive version:

```
function recAddSubArrayToSet(setA, B, j):
    if j >= length(B):
        return setA
    setA.add(B[j])
    return recAddSubArrayToSet(setA, B, j + 1)

function recSetIncludesSubArray(setA, B, j):
    if j >= length(B):
        return true
    if not setA.has(B[j]):
        return false
    return recSetIncludesSubArray(A, B, j + 1)

function recIncludesSubArray(A, B):
    setA = new empty Set
    recAddSubArrayToSet(setA, B, 0)
    return recSetIncludesSubArray(setA, B, 0)
```

### About built-in functions

You wrote that built-in functions are not allowed. This is a constraint that only makes sense when you have a specific target programming language in mind. In pseudo code there is no concept of built-in functions.

Some languages will provide maps/sets/dictionaries in a way where you can *only* do something useful with them by calling methods on them (built-in), while other languages will allow you to apply operators (like `+`) on them, and use an `in` operator to test membership.

But even getting the size of an array may need a function call in some languages. So this constraint really only makes sense in the context of a specific programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You can **convert a loop to recursion by designing a recursive function/method that operates on a part of your original array** (technically on a sub-array) (initially the sub-array will be your complete array) **and reducing the size of the array** (each time you are passing to your recursive method) by 1.

The following method (I've the implementation in Java) simply checks if the given number is present in the array/list. But notice that it also takes `startIndex` and `endIndex` which specifically denotes our boundaries of sub-array/sub-list.

In simple words the following method checks whether the given `number` is present in `list` or not but the check is done only between `startIndex` and `endIndex` both inclusive. Consider that you pass each element of your array `B` (`listB` in my case) to this method, and `list` argument is actually a reference to your array `A` (`listA` in my case).

```
/**
 * This method recursively checks whether given
 * number is contained in the given list or not.
 *
 * For this method startIndex and endIndex
 * correspond to the indices of listA
 */
private static boolean contains(List<Integer> list, int startIndex, int endIndex, int number) {
    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        return list.get(startIndex) == number;
    } else if (startIndex < endIndex) {
        return list.get(startIndex) == number || contains(list, startIndex + 1, endIndex, number);
    }
    // should never be the case
    return true;
}
```

Now, once you have the above method, you can now device a recursive method that pics up all the elements of `listB` one at a time, and "plugs it in" inside the above method. This can be preciously done as follows:

```
/**
 * This method recurse over each element of listB and checks
 * whether the current element is contained in listA or not
 *
 * for this method startIndex and endIndex correspond to the
 * indices of listB
 */
private static boolean contains(List<Integer> listA, List<Integer> listB, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (startIndex > endIndex) {
        return true;
    }
    boolean c = contains(listA, 0, listA.size() - 1, listB.get(startIndex));
    if (!c) {
        return false;
    }
    return contains(listA, listB, startIndex + 1, endIndex);
}
```

And a call to above method will look like `contains(listA, listB, 0, listB.size() - 1)`
Bingo!! You are done.

I'd like you to think of recursive functions in a specific manner. Think of them as like what arguments it take, and what it does. So when you have a recursive call inside the recursive method, you don't need to think how that recursive call will work, rather have an abstraction there and believe that the recursive call will give you the result. Now focus on how you can use this returned result to make this recursive method correctly work.